Is it possible to intercept screen recording requests on MacOS?
I have a few apps that run simultaneously, which all intermittently grab screenshots at different times.  I'd like to intercept these requests and let them hang until I manually hit a button to approve, ideally in some kind of modal or pop up.
The main question I have is whether it is possible to actually intercept these requests in the first place.  The secondary question is whether I can still approve them even after they've been intercepted for a few seconds.  Also, I have never developed an app specifically for MacOS before so any helpful tips would be appreciated.

Do you know how these other apps grab the screen? Do they invoke the/usr/bin/screencapture binary? Or do they use Objective C?
